# Executing ImageMagick from php. Trying to convert first pdf page to png

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, png

I have the following code:

```
$input = "C:/wamp/www/lnu/components/com_djclassifieds/images/item/input.pdf";
$output = "C:/wamp/www/lnu/components/com_djclassifieds/images/item/output.png";
exec("C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16\convert -density 400 {$input}[0] -resize 25% {$output}");
```

I also tried `exec('C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16\convert -density 400 "'.$input.'"[0] -resize 25% "'.$output.'"');`, and it does not work.

I think this should work because in my command line I type: `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16>convert -density 400 "c:/test.pdf"[0] -resize 25% "c:/out.png"`, and it works.

Any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that Apache user has write permission to that file.

Comment: I think that is not the solution but thank you anyway.

Comment: Ok, that helped me a lot. There was a problem with Program Files, so I did this: `exec('C:\"Program Files"\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16\convert -density 400 '.$input.'[0] -resize 25% '.$output);`